# How to write a locator for below code in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

How to write a locator for below html in selenium.

```
<li class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-truncate" data-aura-rendered-by="4698:0">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="New Contact" data-aura-rendered-by="4798:0" class="forceActionLink" data-aura-class="forceActionLink">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="New Contact" data-aura-rendered-by="4799:0">New Contact</div>
    </a>
</li>
```

For above code  i tried with Xpath, link text and class name locator. 
Element is not clicking. Please suggest me to write a locator for above html.

Comment: locator for tag 'a'?

Comment: Can you specify witch tag you want to target? Your question is unclear like this.

Comment: No . For new contact button, i want to click but it is not clicking.

Comment: what is the tag for that contact button? Give the HTML highlighting the contact button tag in it

Comment: @ Thomas , in above html i want to write a locator to click new contact button. I tried with xpath,link text and class name.

Comment: @SrieedherSanthakumar Can you consider to update the question with a bit more of the relevant HTML DOM. Thanks

Comment: is it working manually?

Answer (score 0):

can you try the below xpath,

```
driver.findElement(by.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'New Contact')]")).click();
```

I have assumed there is only one 'li' in the html DOM. If not kindly give me complete DOM. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: driver.findElement(by.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'New Contact']")).click(); I tried above lines of code it is not clicking.

Comment: can you please tell any other measure.

Comment: oops. there was an typo and now corrected it. Check now

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (754, 177). Other element would receive the click: <div class="slds-theme--success slds-notify--toast slds-notify slds-notify--toast forceToastMessage" role="alertdialog" data-aura-rendered-by="4:3288;a" data-aura-class="forceToastMessage">...</div> .For this i used actions class and javascriptExecutor still element is not clicking.

Comment: ok. i got it.. Before selecting the option using my code, we need to make sure that the option is visible. We need to click on the drop down to make the option visible first.  Can you check the DOM and write it?

Comment: element is visible only. I tried using xpath,link text and class name . Element is not clicking. Please suggest any other way to write. Above is my full Dom structure for clicking new contact button.

Comment: any luck on this? driver.findElement(by.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'New Contact')]/parent::a")).click();

Comment: element is not clicking.

Comment: pls help me any other way.

Comment: can you give us teh complete DOM or URL?

Comment: While i am inspecting it is highlighting . U want that particular DOM or u want it from first line.  <li class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-truncate" data-aura-rendered-by="4698:0">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="New Contact" data-aura-rendered-by="4798:0" class="forceActionLink" data-aura-class="forceActionLink">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="New Contact" data-aura-rendered-by="4799:0">New Contact</div>
    </a>
</li> this is dom for clicking new contact button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Xpath `*//div[@title="New Contact"]` or `*//a/div[@title="New Contact"]`

Comment: i have one doubt .*//div[@title="New Contact"] or *//a/div[@title="New Contact"] . This is one xpath or we can write in 2 ways.

Comment: No this is two diff Xpath we can try out with any one

Comment: I tried 2 things.I am getting below error .  unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (754, 177). Other element would receive the click: <div class="slds-theme--success slds-notify--toast slds-notify slds-notify--toast forceToastMessage" role="alertdialog" data-aura-rendered-by="4:3296;a" data-aura-class="forceToastMessage">...</div>

Comment: pls suggest any other measure.

Comment: just add wait before your click event .